# Writing a function that returns true if an integer is between two numbers in Python

Tags: python, function

I have attempted to write a function that has a for loop that returns True if my input was between two numbers. this is what I wrote:

```
def func(x):
    x = list(range(0,1000))
    for n in x:
        if 90 <= n <= 110:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

To my understanding x is between 0 to 10000 and the characters in x which are n, should return True if my input is between 90-110 and false otherwise.

However, this does not work.

I did further research and I found that the following function works
which is:

```
def myfunc(n):
    return (90 <= n <= 110)
```

This function will return true if n is between 90-110

Why is the function that has a for loop did not work ?

Comment: Because you immediately returned `False` on the first value _outside_ that range...

Comment: How would i write the first function in a for loop without returning the wrong answer ?

Answer (score 0):

When using return you get out of the function scope. for it achieve what you want to do you can use a list that contains the boolean values of each case and return that array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the range function:

```
def myfunc(n):
    lower_limit = 90
    upper_limit = 110
    
    number_range = range(lower_limit, upper_limit)
    return (n in number_range)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your `for` is that you're returning `False` first time a number that's not in the range. And because you're creating a list of number from `0 to 1000`, this means that first number will be `0`.

Your script will check `n=0` against `90<=n<=110`. This is `False` so it will `return False`. Returnning a value will end the execution of that function, so the `for` loop is gonna be stopped at the first iteration returning `False`.

You can read [here](https://careerkarma.com/blog/python-return/#:%7E:text=The%20Python%20return%20keyword%20exits,tuple%2C%20or%20any%20other%20object.&text=This%20is%20useful%20because%20it,process%20data%20within%20a%20function.) about `return`